# Java regex - How do I apply regex to get all strings enclosed by ASCII characters?

Tags: java, regex

I'm given a text string that contains ASCII {, }, and ". I'm trying to extract all the strings enclosed by them. I know I'm really new and there're probably a dozen mistakes in my code, so bear with me

In ASCII:

```
{ = %5B
} = %5D
" = %22
```

The Java String is below:

```
"%22key1%22:%5Bvalue1%5D, %22key2%22:%5Bvalue2%5D,"
```

The regex pattern I used is:

```
"%22(.*)%22:%5B(.*)%5D"
```

I wrote the following code below, but the output doesn't seem to be working. What is the right way to do it?

Code:

```
String line = "%22key1%22:%5Bvalue1%5D, %22key2%22:%5Bvalue2%5D,";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("%22(.*)%22:%5B(.*)%5D").matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.print(m.group(i)+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Expected output:

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
```

Actual output:

```
%22key1%22:%5Bvalue1%5D, %22key2%22:%5Bvalue2%5D key1%22:%5Bvalue1%5D, %22key2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the javadoc, capturing group 0 by default is the whole string. It is not included in the `groupCount()`. So with slight modifications you can actually get what you want:

```
String line = "%22key1%22:%5Bvalue1%5D, %22key2%22:%5Bvalue2%5D,";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("%22(.*?)%22:%5B(.*?)%5D").matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.print(m.group(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Please also note the use of reluctant qualifier `?` in the groups, which prevents the matcher from searching for the *last* separator in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your `String` appears to contain URLEncoded values. I would start by using [`URLDecoder.decode(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and then using [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with something like

```
String str = "%22key1%22:%5Bvalue1%5D, %22key2%22:%5Bvalue2%5D,";
try {
    str = URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8");
    String[] kvParts = str.split(",\\s*");
    for (String parts : kvParts) {
        String[] arr = parts.split(":");
        String key = arr[0].substring(1, arr[0].length() - 1);
        String value = arr[1].substring(1, arr[1].length() - 1);
        System.out.printf("%s %s%n", key, value);
    }
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner for you:

```
String input = "%22key1%22:%5Bvalue1%5D, %22key2%22:%5Bvalue2%5D,";

Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(input.replaceAll("%..", "").split(", ?"))
.map(s -> s.split(" ?: ?"))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));

System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{key1=value1, key2=value2}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, regex is greedy. It means if you have a string "aaaaaaaaaa" then regex a*a will match whole string, not just the first "a" because the Kleene star will match as many characters as possible.

In your case you need lazy regex. You can do it using *? or +?. So your expression will look like:

```
%22(.*?)%22:%5B(.*?)%5D
```